# How to debug Samba authorization (authentication) procedure

Tags: logging, authentication, samba, authorization

I'm running a small home network linux-based server which acts as an internet router, torrent client and file server. I have problems connecting Windows clients to server Samba shares ('user name or password is invalid'). How can I enable logging of all stages of Samba authentication/authorization procedure, such as "client connected", "client provided username ... and password ..." etc. so I can find out what exactly is wrong since I'm sure I'm providing proper username and password?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- set logging in smb.conf to level 2 or higher, e.g.

  log level = 3
- watch log files - usually in /var/log/samba/

  tail -F /var/log/samba/log.[client-machine-name]
- look for "authentication for user" ... and context

Comment: This will not log authorisation failure : it will log `4: Authorization Success` instead.  Possibly, this will also provoque a lot of unwanted messages.

Answer (score 0):

In my case no logs were written at all but login kept failing.

My config file was not as valid as i'd expected. With `sudo testparm` i could see that the samba config wasn't valid at all. A similar output could be seen in the `smbd` service's status via `sudo systemctl status smbd.service`.